# Woocommerce doesn't redirect to checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

its me again, i will give you guys a quick rundown of what i'm doing ***(i'm passing the cart info from one woocommerce store to another woocommerce store)***  i was finally able to send the product_id and quantity from the store **A** to the store **B**  and in this one i'm using the woocommerce **WC()->cart** functions to create a copy of the cart in this last store so the client cant process his purchase, and its working well.

Here is the code.

```
  $incoming_cart=unserialize(base64_decode($_POST["p_cart_t"]));

       foreach ( $incoming_cart as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

            $product_id=$cart_item['product_id'];
            $quantity_pro=$cart_item['quantity'];

            print_r($product_id);
            print_r($quantity_pro); 
            WC()->cart->empty_cart();
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id,$quantity_pro);

            }
```

My problem is, when i press checkout the system sends me to the cart page again like just refresh and the cart info gets lost.

I have to say that i'm passing the info of the cart that comes from store **A** to the **cart-empty.ph**p file from the store **B** cause since im switching between stores  there is no cart in the store **B** and it says that the cart is empty, so what i did was  paste the **cart.php** code into **cart-empty.php** and its working, the file  is  catching the info and mirroring the cart but i have this problem with the checkout.

- ¿do someone may know what this is happening?
- ¿what can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I can sense a logic of execution problem here.
One question is where and when are you firing that code you provided. I would suggest, fire it on `woocommerce_loaded` hook. Then after adding everything to cart, redirect to cart page.

WooCommerce has an option that after adding a product to cart, you will be redirected to cart. I suggest you look for that.

Also, I can't help myself noticing that your code is emptying the cart in every loop. I would transfer `WC()->cart->empty_cart();` outside `foreach` loop. Maybe after checking `$incoming_cart` is non empty, empty your cart, then run a loop to add all the products from `$incoming_cart`. Then redirect the page to the cart page. By this time the cart is not empty.

With this, you don't have to edit files from WooCommerce. Forget editing `cart-empty.php`